# Need matching Django ORM query with SQL

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models

I have table structure like below and my input is like 2018

| id | registration_year |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2014-2016 |
| 2 | 2017-2019 |

My sql query is like below,

```
SELECT id FROM table_name 
WHERE
SUBSTRING(registeration_year,1,4) <= 2018 
AND 
SUBSTRING(registeration_year,6,4) >= 2018
```

then id will be 2.

How to convert it into Django ORM query?

Comment: While you *can* do this, the modeling is not a good idea. Use two integer fields... IIRC you already asked that here, and got the very same advise.

Comment: I hate to be like this, but it seems like you are asking stackoverflow to write your code step by step as opposed to reading the documentation... Please listen to people when they tell you what could be done better. Consider it a learning experience. Refactoring isn't always easy, but it IS nescessary a whole lot of times. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/database-functions/